# How do you place images side by side/in a grid with their captions in CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

I'm having difficulties in trying to place the 5 images side by side, and the code I have so far is posted below, HTML:

```
    <ul>
      <li class="container">
        <img class="productlist" src="img/shop-1.jpg" alt="shop1" />
        <span class="caption">Quisque congue ipsum</span>
        <span class="caption">lorem</span>
      </li>

      <li class="container">
        <img class="productlist" src="img/shop-2.jpg" alt="shop2" />
        <span class="caption">Curabitur pharetra</span>
        <span class="caption">lorem</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.productlist {
  display: block;
  width: 45%;

}

.caption {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/marudhupandiyang/wtxd7vvu/

Comment: @Panther Thank You!, this worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

change your css this way

```
.container {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
   width: 45%;
}

.productlist {
  display: block;


}

.caption {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width in `.container` div

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 45%;
}
.productlist {
  display: block;
}
.caption {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="container">
    <img class="productlist" src="img/shop-1.jpg" alt="shop1" />
    <span class="caption">Quisque congue ipsum</span>
    <span class="caption">lorem</span>
  </li>

  <li class="container">
    <img class="productlist" src="img/shop-2.jpg" alt="shop2" />
    <span class="caption">Curabitur pharetra</span>
    <span class="caption">lorem</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```